# Have a problem computing pearson p-value for dict values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, pearson

I want to compute the pearson p value for values of two dictionaries using for loop.
Dictionaries represent the data of two dataframes one of which has some changes.
The dictionaries contain the info on the name of columns, the keys and the histogram values for each column. So basically I want to compute the p values for each column for these two dictionaries

both of the dictionaries have the following structure:

```
{'columnname1': {'keys': [0, 46.72, 50], 'values': [41, 13, 23, 21...0, 0, 1]},
'columnname2': {'keys': [0, 20, 50], 'values': [21, 43, 25, 2...0, 3, 15},...}
```

To compute the p-value for each column I tried to do the next function:

```py
    def ChiTest(hist_1, hist_2):
    hist = {}
    for column1 in hist_1.keys():
        for column2 in hist_1.keys():
            hist[column1] = {}
            hist[column1]['keys'] = hist_2[column2]['keys']
            hist[column1]['pearson'] = pearsonr(hist_1[column1]['values'], hist_2[column2]['values'])
    return (hist)


test = ChiTest(one, two)
```

The hist[column]['keys'] work well but the **hist[column]['pearson'] = pearsonr(hist_2[column]['values'], hist_1[column]['values'])** raise the KeyError message

```
KeyError: 'values'
```

And I can't figure out what have I missed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @AAA fixed it, thanks. didn't notice while editing

Comment: Can you post how you are calling ChiTest?

Comment: @Ison, you may have to put a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, how does 'ShortData' come in?. Can the code you have put here be used to debug this issue?

Comment: @AAA. ShortData == keys. fixed it in post. IRL one dict uses ShortData name and another keys. Both mean "keys".  So yes, the code can be used in gebugging

Comment: @Ison the code above works with no error: see [here](https://repl.it/repls/MiniBeautifulConferences)

Comment: @AAA. Hmmm, seems problem is not in the func. Ok...Thanks for help!

Comment: @Ison, probably had to do with you using `column` in both for loops

Answer (score 1):

Well, now the original answer is obsolete.
What keys do you want in hist output?
This is probably wrong;  what do you want hist to return?

```
for column1 in hist_1.keys():
    for column2 in hist_2.keys():
        hist[(column1, column2)] = {}
        hist[(column1, column2)]['keys'] = hist_2[column2]['keys']
        hist[(column1, column2)]['pearson'] = pearsonr(hist_2[column2]['values'], hist_1[column1]['values'])
```

(Not clear what you are trying to get to :))

Comment: @Ison: Still using "column" in both loops; that can't work; column will always be a key of hist_2, but not hist_1 inside the inner loop